# Git alias parameter completion doesn't work in Zsh

Tags: macos, git, zsh, zsh-completion

I encounter a problem with Zsh autocompletion for some specific git commands (the ones involving a remote and a branch), but only when using aliases.

Here is an example with `push`:

```
$ git push o<TAB>rigin m<TAB>aster  # tab completion works
$ git config --global alias.ps push # set a `ps` alias for `push`
$ git ps o<TAB>rigin m<TAB>         # tab completion doesn't work for "master"
```

The same problem occurs with `pull` and `fetch`.

My `.zshrc` can be found [here](https://github.com/aymericbeaumet/dotfiles/blob/master/src/.zshrc), but I don't think it is related, as I was able to reproduce the problem without using it (just enabling the autocompletion with `autoload -U compinit && compinit`).

I'm running OSX 10.9 with the following software versions (both of them installed through `brew`):

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0)
$ git --version
git version 1.8.4.2
```

This problem appeared since I did an OSX 10.9 clean install. So I presume it comes from a recent update either from Zsh or Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from a bug in the Git completion for both Bash and Zsh. [@felipec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10474/felipec) took the time [to fix it](https://github.com/felipec/git/commit/b7b6be72d60d5d5fc308a0bb7d48508ff70f3998). Thanks, it works like a charm now!

Comment: Hm, I still have this issue - was this fixed using git's git-completion.zsh instead of Zsh? Or is it fixed in an update to Zsh?

Comment: I installed @felipec completion files: https://github.com/felipec/git/blob/fc/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash and https://github.com/felipec/git/blob/fc/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh, it works well.

Comment: Ah awesome, thanks! I'm using git's completion files, which I assume are closer to felipec's than zsh's completion is, and the one thing I miss is Zsh's autocompletion gave descriptions of aliases. So for example, if I had lg='log --graph' as an alias, git l<Tab> would show lg, along with what it was aliased to. Ah well, this is probably worth more.

Comment: still has this problem. and above link is dead

Comment: It's been merged upstream since, so you can try these links: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash and https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh. Also, I guess you shouldn't face this issue with an updated install? What os/git versions are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use Git's official completion for zsh:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh